# Compilation Eror: One contract accessing the variable of another contract

Tags: solc, solidity-0.5.x

I am trying to compile two contracts. I am getting 'balance' variable error in "HoneyPotCollect.sol" contract. Is balance not a global contract variable? Somebody please guide me how to correct my error.

//HoneyPot.sol

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
      contract HoneyPot {
      mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    
      constructor() payable public {
        put();
      }
    
      function put() payable public {
        balances[msg.sender] = msg.value; // msg.sender here is the address from the sender
      }
    
      function get() public {
         (bool success,) = msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])("");
          success = false;
          //revert();
        
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
      }

  function() external {
    revert();
  }
}
```

//HoneyPotCollect contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import './HoneyPot.sol';

contract HoneyPotCollect {
  HoneyPot public honeypot;

  constructor(address _honeypot) public {

    honeypot = HoneyPot(_honeypot);
  }

  function kill () public {
    selfdestruct(msg.sender);
  }

  function collect() payable public {
    honeypot.put.value(msg.value)();
    honeypot.get();
  }

  function () external payable  {
    if (honeypot.balance >= msg.value) {
      honeypot.get();
    }
  }
}
```

Following is my error message:

> $ solc HoneyPotCollect.sol
>
> HoneyPotCollect.sol:19:9: Error: Member "balance" not found or not
> visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract HoneyPot. Use
> "address(honeypot).balance" to access this address member.
>
> ```
> if (honeypot.balance >= msg.value) {
>     ^--------------^
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> Is `balance` not a global contract variable?

No, but it's a member of the `address` type, so change this:

```
honeypot.balance
```

To this:

```
address(honeypot).balance
```

See [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types) for more details.